# IP blacklisted RATS Dyna

Tags: ip, blacklist

My IP is on blacklist RATS Dyna.
**Anyone can help me what to do to delist IP?**

```
inet 91.102.115.84/28 brd 91.102.115.95 scope global eth4
inet 91.102.115.85/28 brd 91.102.115.95 scope global secondary eth4:0
inet 91.102.115.86/28 brd 91.102.115.95 scope global secondary eth4:1
inet 91.102.115.87/28 brd 91.102.115.95 scope global secondary eth4:2
inet 91.102.115.88/28 brd 91.102.115.95 scope global secondary eth4:3
inet 91.102.115.89/28 brd 91.102.115.95 scope global secondary eth4:4
inet 91.102.115.90/28 brd 91.102.115.95 scope global secondary eth4:5
inet 91.102.115.91/28 brd 91.102.115.95 scope global secondary eth4:6
inet 91.102.115.92/28 brd 91.102.115.95 scope global secondary eth4:7
inet 91.102.115.93/28 brd 91.102.115.95 scope global secondary eth4:8
inet 91.102.115.94/28 brd 91.102.115.95 scope global secondary eth4:9
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should start with WHY did it happen. There are lots of reasons and I wont go in detaul but usually is:

- bad configuration (no PTR records, missing SPF, missing DKIM )
- actual spamming (host got infected and started blasting viagra emails )
- new domains sending emails too soon (this might sound weird but from my experience i've seen that a domain must have at least 14 days around to be able to send mails that wont go directly into spam, gmail would flag that as spam most of the times

Try to figure what whats your case using diagnostics (mxtoolbox.com to find problems). When you end up in a blacklist you usually are pointed to a localhost address and the end is usually a code (`127.0.0.X`, `127.0.0.2` for `no ptr` for example, `127.0.0.1` for plain `spam` , `127.0.0.5` for `exploits and bots` and so on) but these are not standard and they differ from one RBL to another 
After finding the why try scanning your host with anti-malware if thats the case.